# Does setting BIOS SATA RAID/AHCI mode to RAID will activate RAID operation upon new hard disk insertion?

Tags: hard-drive, bios, raid, jbod

Each BIOS 'SATA RAID/AHCI' mode comes with at least 3 different mode - Disable/IDE or RAID or AHCI.

Does setting the 'SATA RAID/AHCI' mode to 'RAID' will cause the following:

1. RAID 1 activated when 2 hard drives is inside the desktop machine.
2. RAID 3 activated when 3 hard drives is inside the desktop machine.

or the RAID mode will remain as JBOD (Just a Bunch of Disks - each drive functions independently of one another and no redundancy is supported)

(Suppose that the hard disks were of the same size.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the motherboard, but most probably, if you enable this option, you will have a new message during boot allowing you to press a key combination which would run a small utility for configuring RAID mode and other related settings. Watch your boot sequence carefully.

Answer (score 0):

RAID is never activating itself automatically. Setting the mode in BIOS only allows for RAID configuration in general, but the actual configuration must be done with a utility which is usually accessible on boot by a certain hotkey, just watch your BIOS boot messages when the computer is starting.
The actual key depends on your BIOS, you may find that right key by using Google with the name of your mainboard.

Comment: There are low-end hardware RAID solutions that configure themselves automatically or by jumpers. Typically they're devices that allow more than one drive to present as a single drive and so they have no user interface.